# sending email to multiple recipients not see other users addresses

Tags: php, email

hello friend me sending registered users activation link and code on their email address via admin panel and it working fine users can get acivtation link and code.

but problem is that `users can see other recipients email address In To:` i want users cannot see others recipients email address?

**here my code**

```
<?php 
//creating activation code
$alpha = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
$length = 11;
for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++){
$ran = rand(0, strlen($alpha)-1);
$new_key .= substr($alpha, $ran, 1);
}   


$activation = 'activation.php?email='.urlencode($_POST['email1']).'&key='.$new_key;
$your_email = 'test@test.com'; 
$domain = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
$to = implode(',', $_POST['email1']);
$subject = 'Confirmation';
$message = '<font class="font1">
<a href="http://'.$domain.'/'.$activation.'">http://'.$domain.'/'.$activation.'</a></font>';

$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= "From: <$your_email>\r\n" .  
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion(); 

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

**form where selecting users email address**

```
<form name ="checkForm" id="checkForm" method="post">  
<?php 
$query=mysql_query("select semail from students order by id") 
or die ('students query');

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
?>

<input type="text" name="email1[]" value="<?php echo $row['semail'] ?>"  />

<?php } ?> 

</form>
```

Comment: Send multiple emails, not one... or just add them as BCC.

Comment: yes but users can see other `recipients email address`

Comment: Just loop the mail function and send it to each users

Answer (score 1):

Use BCC

```
$headers .= 'From: Your Name <test@test.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'BCC: '.  implode(',', $_POST['email1']) . "\r\n";

mail(null, $title, $content, $headers);
```

Comment: if i used bcc then what about to ?? is that possible bcc work instead of to?

Comment: Usually you add yourself as the "to" because everyone you're sending to can see your email without issue.

Comment: Or you can make it as null

Comment: thanks shafeeq it is working dude but what about `TO IS BLANK IN The EMail`

Comment: See the header From Your Name